# Possible to pack bounding boxes and labels with images in RecordIO?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, mxnet

I'm trying to use MXNet/Gluon to train an Object Detection model (specifically multiple instances of one type of object within an image), and the im2rec tool does not appear to add bounding box information to the .rec file.

`mxnet.recordio.pack_img()` appears to do the work of packing the image and the label together, but I can't find where/how to include bounding box information in pixel space.  From the documentation:

```
label = 4 # label can also be a 1-D array, for example: label = [1,2,3]
id = 2574
header = mx.recordio.IRHeader(0, label, id, 0)
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
packed_s = mx.recordio.pack_img(header, img)
```

The header doesn't have a spot for bounding box info.  Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found the answer.  The packaging of the labels in the .lst file can take an expanded set of information.  The [documentation](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/image.html) here describes how that information is expected.

What is left, then, is to edit [im2rec.py](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/tools/im2rec.py) to replace the mere label index with the expanded information (lines 50 and 60 as of this writing). Something like:

```
def parse_label_file(fp):
    with open(fp, 'r') as f:
        data = f.readlines() # or json.load() if appropriate
        ### Some code here to parse and return the image dimensions
        ### width, height, id, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
    return (4, 5, width, id, height, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)

...
label_file_path = path[:-4] + ".txt" # or .json as appropriate
if path not in cat:
    cat[path] = parse_label_file(label_file_path)
...
```